Receive Data Stream At Once With Service Call
I've a backend controller with C# that takes two parameters to return data for user permission. This works for one user at a time, now I've a scenario to use the same controller to return data of multiple users at a time. Note: I've to use the same controller and no changes can be done in the backend at present. The controller returns a list with required permission for a user currently.
Without much thought and delay, I did the following that seems working but not getting the result set at one go. Here's the code snippet I've now:
//This works selecting a drop down box value
filterUsers() {
  this.filteredUsers.items = [...this.dataSrc.items.filter(x => this.filterUsersFunc(x, this.filterState))]; //Initial values are here when drop down box selection done 
  this.filteredUsers.total = this.filteredUsers.items.length;

  console.log("Filtered Users below:");
  console.log(this.filteredUsers.items);

  //Depending upon initial values and iterating them, like to have user permission for multiple users
  for (var i = 0; i < this.filteredUsers.items.length; i++) {
    this.userId = 0;
    console.log(this.filteredUsers.items[i].id);
    this.userId = this.filteredUsers.items[i].id;

    this.userService
      .getExploreUserPermissionSettings(this.filteredUsers.items[i]?.id, this.filteredUsers.items[i]?.enterpriseId) //Passing parameters from the loop
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.busy = false))
      .subscribe((response) => {
       
        console.log("User Ids:");
        console.log(this.filteredUsers.items[i]?.id);

        let obj = {} as ExploreUserPermissionSettingItemArr; //Then trying to save them in an object
        obj.userId = this.userId; //Even the user id doesn't get changed in each iteration, it only takes the last user id each time
        obj.newArr = response.data.included;

        console.log("In For Loop:");
        console.log(obj);

        this.userPermissionsIncluded.push(obj); //Finally adding them to an array
      });
  }

  console.log("User Permissions Below:");
  console.log(this.userPermissionsIncluded); //Lastly trying to see the result set
} 

Interesting thing is, the last statement console.log(this.userPermissionsIncluded); comes to top in the console log of the browser and later getting the values in a stream as follows shown in the screenshot:

I know, am doing something wrong here. But is there a way to get the stream at one go and save them in an array at once? Say I've 20 users on filtering and this 20 users data should be in the array rather iterating one by one that I've now, shown in the screenshot.
One more thing, I get the user ids from the for loop and it passes the id to the controller correctly. But when I save it to the object obj.userId = this.userId;, it only sets the last user id from the loop as you can see in the screenshot.

...how is this a "stream", exactly?

The C# code is giving a 500, perhaps you should be posting that as well?

There are some issues with your code

Main problem is that you are trying to send request for every user in loop. It is considered bad practise since it can cause a lot of network overload and lead to performance issues. You should rather be using something like get for all users like


GET users

and maybe

GET users/id

for each individual user

Reason why the last statement


console.log(this.userPermissionsIncluded);

comes to the top is because it is outside of subscription and therefore it doesn't need to wait for request to complete and will be displayed first. You should read more about mechanism called event loop in javascript to better understand this.

Using var is bad practise since it works on function scope which leads to many bugs and misunderstandings. Better use let in this case since it works with block scope. You can read about it here

I did some refactor to your code but still I think that you should use different endpoint for such task.
//This works selecting a drop down box value
filterUsers() {
  this.filteredUsers.items = [...this.dataSrc.items.filter(x => this.filterUsersFunc(x, this.filterState))]; //Initial values are here when drop down box selection done 
  this.filteredUsers.total = this.filteredUsers.items.length;

  console.log("Filtered Users below:", this.filteredUsers.items);
  //Depending upon initial values and iterating them, like to have user permission for multiple users
  for (let i = 0; i < this.filteredUsers.items.length; i++) {
    this.userId = 0;
    console.log(this.filteredUsers.items[i].id);
    this.userId = this.filteredUsers.items[i]?.id;

    this.userService
      .getExploreUserPermissionSettings(this.userId, this.filteredUsers.items[i]?.enterpriseId) //Passing parameters from the loop
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.busy = false))
      .subscribe((response) => {

        console.log("User Ids:", this.userId);

        let obj = {} as ExploreUserPermissionSettingItemArr; //Then trying to save them in an object
        obj.userId = this.userId; //Even the user id doesn't get changed in each iteration, it only takes the last user id each time
        obj.newArr = response.data.included;

        console.log("In For Loop:", obj);

        this.userPermissionsIncluded.push(obj); //Finally adding them to an array
      });
  }
} 


GET users - OP implied doesn't exist and cannot be created hence the front end hitting the back end X times for X users

The let actually worked to set the user ids in the object properties, Thanks for that @Thomas.
